# A or B but not Both - Can't figure it out

Tags: probability

According to a survey in one U.S. city, 49% of women between the ages and 25 of 35 are married, 47% are working full time, and 21% are married and working full time. If a woman between the ages of 25 and 35 is picked at random from the city, what is the probability that she is working full time or married but
not both?

So I am given the above question, and I thought it was rather simple but I can't seem to figure it out. The answer key says that the answer is 0.54 but I keep getting 0.75, what am I doing wrong?

$(0.49+0.47)-0.21 = 0.75$ 
The logic here is that we want women working full time(0.47) and women that are married(0.49) but not both(0.21)

Comment: Have you drawn the Venn diagram yet?

Comment: No, I have not. If i was too, what would I put on the outside of the circles?

Comment: It should become obvious as soon as you draw and label the parts of the diagram.  Two intersecting circles create four regions whose frequencies need to sum to 100%.

Comment: I must be missing something here. If I have one circle of 49 and one circle of 47, then I get a total of 96. Then there is the little part of intersection with 21. Are you saying 100-96 is supposed to be 4 on the outside?

Comment: I hope you're looking at the drawing as you read this.  Since the two circles overlap with 21% overlap, it will be graphically obvious that there is much more than 4% outside their union.

Comment: Yea I'm completely lost. Thanks for your help though

Comment: $P(A\oplus B) = P(A)+P(B)-2P(A\cap B)$.

Comment: The problem is the 0.49 includes the 0.21 for both, and the 0.47 includes the 0.21 for both. When you added them, you counted "both" twice. You need to count it zero times, but you only subtracted it off once. See the Venn diagram [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/181154/x-amount-of-people-drink-coffee-y-amount-of-people-drink-tea-z-amount-of-peopl/181160#181160) and make the relevant substitutions of name and probability.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the 0.49 includes the 0.21 ("both"), and the 0.47 includes the 0.21 as well. When you added them, you counted "both" twice.

You need to count it zero times, but you only subtracted it off once in your calculations.

See the Venn diagram [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/181154/x-amount-of-people-drink-coffee-y-amount-of-people-drink-tea-z-amount-of-peopl/181160#181160), which with the appropriate substitution of labels and values, should make it easy to see.