# x amount of people drink coffee, y amount of people drink tea, z amount of people drink both

Tags: probability, self-study

> There are coffee drinkers and there are tea drinkers and among them
>   there are those who like both.  Among the management students it was
>   found that the probability that the student drinks coffee is 0.32, the
>   probability that the student drinks tea is 0.45,  and the probability
>   that the student drinks both is 0.26.
>
> What is the probability that the student doesn't drink tea?

if .45 of people drink tea then 1-.45 of people don't drink tea?

> What is the probability that the student drinks neither coffee nor tea?

.45+.32 people drink tea or coffee so 1 - .45+.32 drink neither?

> What is the probability that the student drinks coffee or tea?

.45+.32 people drink coffee or tea?

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Comment: Note that your attempted arithmetic does not match the General Rule of Addition.

Comment: Go back to your General Rule of Addition. What does the output of that give you? How do you apply it using the #'s you were provided? & how are the 2nd & 3rd questions in the problem related?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It may help to draw a [Venn diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram) and fill in the parts you know:

[image]

You know the entire content of the "Coffee" circle, the "Tea" circle and also the overlap. You know the probability of the entire box is 1.

From those you can work out the content of each "piece" (Coffee-only, Tea-only, Neither and you already have Both), like so:

[image]

and from those pieces all the questions are immediately answered.

Comment: How did you draw them?

Comment: I just knocked those up in Paint, actually. Nothing fancy; just drew a round-corner box, a couple of nearly circular ellipses (made them slightly flat for more overlap) typed some text and did a little manipulation with select and erase and so on.

Comment: Ah, back to basics I guess. I was hoping they were generated by a simple library :)

Comment: If I was trying to do something reproducible (say for a book or an article or some notes), perhaps I'd draw them in R. But there's no need for a one-off.

Answer (score 0):

*What is the probability that the student drinks neither coffee nor tea?*

I will calculate the % of people who just drink tea, and just drink coffee.

```
  drinks tea is 0.45
-drinks both is 0.26
====================
drinks just tea 0.19 


  drinks coffee is 0.32
   -drinks both is 0.26
=======================
drinks just coffee 0.06
```

Then the problem is much less tricky:

What is the probability that the student drinks neither coffee nor tea?
1 (All) - .06 (Cof) -.19 (Tea) - .26 (Both) = .49

Feel free to ask questions.  Sorry about any formatting problems.

Once you get the hang it this, you can jump to:
1-.45-.32+.26=.49 
or 1 - (.45 Tea/Both +.32 Coff/Both -.26 Both) The minus both is because both would have gotten counted twice.

That is really the main trick of the problem, you must not count the both group twice.

Comment: Note: You seemed to get the rest right.

Comment: I didn't understand why I needed to count both twice but its because you are subtracting it from 100%